# Creating E-Commerce WebSite What is To Be Use ( Session Or Cookie) In asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am Creating E-Commerece Website For Kirana Using Session Of Data Table But Now I want To Use Cookie To Reduce Traffic With Cloud Is This Safe method Or not?  I try to Use Cookie and pass parameter of session id to it to remove (i.e. Clear Session Variable) when  Shopping is completed but it is not working still cookies are store in to the browser. Please Specify me the solution?

Comment: you can expire the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are delicious, nomnomnom (XD just kidding). Some clients have their cookies disabled. "Cookies CAN be used for malicious purposes though" -from http://www.allaboutcookies.org/

For me, Sessions are safer

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be edited by a user.

Sessions are strictly serve based and can be controlled on the server side.

Session is the way to go. That way you can keep information about each user in their own unique session.